# Locating a copy of Sifra (Torat Kohanim)

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash, pentateuch-chumash, sifra-toras-cohanim

Now that we are starting Sefer Vayikra, this seems like an opportune time to ask a question that has been bugging me for years! Where can I find a good copy of Sifra (aka "Torat Kohanim")? A surprising number of publications include only the first two sections: *Dibbura deChova* and *Dibbura diNedava*, while some others (such as the  אוצר הפירושים מלבי״ם) include also the Mechilta, Sifrei Bemidbar and Sifrei Devarim.

I am looking for a printed copy of the Sifra - *only* the Sifra, but the *complete* Sifra. Does anybody know where I can find it?

Comment: Will check my father's copy and a quick internet search soon

Comment: How important is it that it be ONLY Sifra, by which I assume you mean no commentaries? Most seforim stores sell an edition with the Chofetz Chaim's commentary, which is pretty minimal (he mainly just adds a few words of clarification or explains girsa changes of the gra)

Comment: @Matt - It's only important to me that it not contain other midrashim. I have no problem with its including a commentary, particularly if it's unobtrusive. Do you have a link for this product? My city only has the one seforim store, so an online source is preferable.

Comment: I bought mine in Israel but I've seen them in bookstores around the NY/NJ area. It's on otzar hachachmah too

Comment: Wiki has the text: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90 and HB has the original scan: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/38154 and publishyoursefer will sell you a physical copy: http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/t/30092

Comment: @Bachrach44 - Publishyoursefer provides an excellent service (and hebrewbooks.org is amazing), but I can't think of anything worse than needing to pore over a computer-generated scan of a 16th century publication when all I want to do is learn the midrash. Thanks anyway, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here  http://www.publishersrow.com/ebookshuk/cart/shopproductdetail.asp?o=1434949200000&id=10102

This is the text prepared by Finkelstein.

Comment: Not true, unfortunately. I have that edition at home; it's beautiful, and it contains a lot of good scholarship, but it is incomplete. It only includes the first two sections of Sifra (*Dibbura deChova* and *Dibbura diNedava*), despite what many publishers are saying about it. I can only justify this on the basis of the fact that the companies selling this book have evidently never read it.

Answer (score 1):

The Sifra can be found on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra?lang=bi) or [HebrewBooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/38154).

While these aren't physical copies-- as @[PopularismIsn'tRight](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5459/popularisntright) notes in a comment-- you can have a physical copy printed via using [PublishYourSefer](http://www.publishyoursefer.com/).